# Testing links with rspec and cabybara: old and new syntax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, capybara

In the old syntax of rspec I could do something like this:

```
It "should have the right URL" do 
  get :show, :id => @user
  response.should have_selector('td>a', :content => user_path(@user), 
                                        :href => user_path(@user))
end
```

In the new sintax we can do this:

```
It "should have the right URL" do 
 visit user_path(@user) 
 expect(page).to have_link user_path(@user), href: user_path(@user)
end
```

But, in the new syntax of rspec and using capybara, how can I say where the link should be? In the first example I say that it's in 'td>a', what about the second example?

Thanks!

Editing:

If I try this:

```
It "should have the right URL" do 
 expect(page).to have_selector('td>a', :content => user_path(@user), 
                                        :href => user_path(@user))
```

I get the following error:

```
  1) UsersController GET 'show' should have the right URL
 Failure/Error: expect(page).to have_selector(:content => user_path(@user),
 ArgumentError:
   invalid keys :content, :href, should be one of :text, :visible, :between, :count, :maximum, :minimum, :exact, :match, :wait
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you also upgraded your capybara [gem](https://github.com/apotonick/rspec-cells/issues/26)?

Try:

```
It "should have the right URL" do 
  expect(page).to have_selector("td>a[href='#{user_path(@user)}']", 
    :text=> user_path(@user))
```

Answer (score 0):

I presume when you say 'new syntax' you refer to the 'expect' syntax instead of the 'should' syntax - you've got two entirely different types of tests there. One looks like a controller spec, one looks like a feature spec.

The only differences with the syntax is that you replace `should` with `expect.to`, eg. `response.should have_selector` becomes `expect(response).to have_selector`.

Comment: But if I use the have_selector exactly like it is in my first example I get the following error: 
invalid keys :link, :href, should be one of :text, :visible, :between, :count, :maximum, :minimum, :exact, :match, :wait

Comment: Please post the exact code with the exact error, because you have no key `:link` in that code.